# Ignore a certain window for Alt-Tab

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

Is it possible to tell a Windows7 application to not appear in the alt-tab list? I often run a VirtualBox virtual machine, and if I don't pay attention (happens often, sigh), I'll switch to the VM unintentionally. The next alt-tab press will happen within the VM, which is obviously not what I want. I'd like to tell VirtualBox to not appear in the alt-tab list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VirtualBox has a checkbox called "Auto Capture Keyboard" (> File > Preferences > Input).  Turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you. It has an exclusion list.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7vistaxp-alt-tab-replacement/